# Is it possible to push video content from a mobile app to Instagram stories by using Instagram API?

Tags: instagram-api, mobile-application

Is it possible to push video content from a mobile app to Instagram stories by using Instagram API?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Instagram doesn't allow API calls to post content

Comment: Do you have a link to a page that confirms this?

Comment: Check API documentation, there is no supported API to post stories or posts